# Granting an Ampps privileges to edit hosts file

Tags: windows-7, hosts-file, ampps

How could I grant an application such as Ampps privileges to be able to edit hosts file. I need such feature to easily handle local Vhosts using it.

I use Windows 7 64 bit and Ampps ver. 2.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` in Explorer. Right click on `hosts` file. Settings > Security: change the write access.

Comment: Solution doesn't work, tried already. Tried again. Nothing to do.

Answer (score -1):

By [Disabling UAC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/turn-user-account-control-on-off).

Please search and  read about UAC before disabling the same.

Comment: Oh! I realized there is a more secure solution, such as making windows regarding an application as a user and setting a permission for that user to edit hosts file only.